# Task :expo-camera:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED when building release apk with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, camera-view

I am trying to build a release apk with react-native, and i am using a expo-camera and selected minimal react-native build when creating the project. I got errors linked to the cameraview folder in node_modules, then got `Task :expo-camera:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED`.
I've added the `maven { // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven" }` line to the `android/build.gradle` file, still getting the same result

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

````
> Task :expo-camera:compileReleaseKotlin
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraModule.kt: (22, 39): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryDelegatee: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraModule.kt: (22, 64): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryDelegatee: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraModule.kt: (23, 5): Unresolved reference: ExportedModule
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraModule.kt: (26, 50): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraModule.kt: (27, 26): Unresolved reference: UIManager
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (35, 3): 'onDropViewInstance' overrides nothing  
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (36, 20): Unresolved reference: UIManager        
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (36, 33): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (41, 3): 'getName' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (43, 3): 'getViewManagerType' overrides nothing  
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (43, 39): Unresolved reference: ViewManagerType  
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (45, 3): 'createViewInstance' overrides nothing  
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (48, 3): 'getExportedEventNames' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (52, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (57, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (62, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (67, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (72, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (77, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (82, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (87, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (92, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (97, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (102, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (107, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\CameraViewManager.kt: (112, 4): Unresolved reference: ExpoProp
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (31, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (32, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (33, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (34, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (35, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (61, 39): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryDelegate
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (61, 64): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryDelegate
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (63, 3): Unresolved reference: LifecycleEventListener
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (70, 43): Unresolved reference: Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (71, 47): Unresolved reference: Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (72, 51): Unresolved reference: Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (73, 37): Unresolved reference: Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (76, 29): Unresolved reference: EventEmitter        
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (76, 45): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (134, 55): Unresolved reference: Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (152, 52): Unresolved reference: Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (181, 68): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (206, 3): 'onHostResume' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (213, 70): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (226, 3): 'onHostPause' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (234, 3): 'onHostDestroy' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (240, 44): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (275, 20): Unresolved reference: UIManager
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (275, 33): Not enough information to infer type variable T
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\ExpoCameraView.kt: (300, 11): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\BarCodeScannedEvent.kt: (7, 21): Unresolved reference: core     
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\BarCodeScannedEvent.kt: (10, 51): Unresolved reference: BaseEvent
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\BarCodeScannedEvent.kt: (26, 3): 'getCoalescingKey' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\BarCodeScannedEvent.kt: (31, 3): 'getEventName' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\BarCodeScannedEvent.kt: (33, 3): 'getEventBody' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraMountErrorEvent.kt: (7, 21): Unresolved reference: core   
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraMountErrorEvent.kt: (9, 53): Unresolved reference: BaseEvent
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraMountErrorEvent.kt: (16, 3): 'getEventName' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraMountErrorEvent.kt: (18, 3): 'getEventBody' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraReadyEvent.kt: (6, 21): Unresolved reference: core        
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraReadyEvent.kt: (8, 48): Unresolved reference: BaseEvent   
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraReadyEvent.kt: (9, 3): 'getEventName' overrides nothing   
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\CameraReadyEvent.kt: (11, 3): 'getEventBody' overrides nothing  
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FaceDetectionErrorEvent.kt: (6, 21): Unresolved reference: core 
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FaceDetectionErrorEvent.kt: (10, 55): Unresolved reference: BaseEvent
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FaceDetectionErrorEvent.kt: (17, 3): 'getCoalescingKey' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FaceDetectionErrorEvent.kt: (19, 3): 'getEventName' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FaceDetectionErrorEvent.kt: (21, 3): 'getEventBody' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FacesDetectedEvent.kt: (9, 50): Unresolved reference: BaseEvent
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FacesDetectedEvent.kt: (23, 3): 'getCoalescingKey' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FacesDetectedEvent.kt: (27, 3): 'getEventName' overrides nothinge: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\FacesDetectedEvent.kt: (29, 3): 'getEventBody' overrides nothinge: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\PictureSavedEvent.kt: (7, 21): Unresolved reference: core       
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\PictureSavedEvent.kt: (9, 49): Unresolved reference: BaseEvent  
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\PictureSavedEvent.kt: (16, 3): 'getCoalescingKey' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\PictureSavedEvent.kt: (26, 3): 'getEventName' overrides nothing 
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\events\PictureSavedEvent.kt: (28, 3): 'getEventBody' overrides nothing 
e:  C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\tasks\ResolveTakenPictureAsyncTask.kt: (44, 24): Unresolved reference: 
Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\tasks\ResolveTakenPictureAsyncTask.kt: (52, 47): Unresolved reference: 
Promise
e: C:\Users\okoli\vscode\instagramCloneRN\node_modules\expo-camera\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\camera\tasks\ResolveTakenPictureAsyncTask.kt: (58, 41): Unresolved reference: 
Promise

> Task :expo-camera:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-camera:compileReleaseKotlin'.```
````

Comment: Instead of adding screenshot of `build.gradle`, please add the code snippet as text.

Comment: done.. Any help?